# WebView in android4.2

Tags: android, webview

i am using webview to load data on android.it is loading good but when i touch the webview it is crashing the application with the following error message.i am facing this problem in android 4.2
can you people tell me why this is happening like this.

i am loading webview by foolowing code

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code,

```
WebView w=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
w.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.mobilea.pcma.org/mobile/xml/sisap.asp?sid="+str+"&pn=AboutUs", Hold,"text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

**exception details:**

```
01-31 06:27:54.768: W/Trace(1148): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-31 06:27:54.768: E/InputEventReceiver(1148): Exception dispatching input event.
01-31 06:27:54.778: D/AndroidRuntime(1148): Shutting down VM
01-31 06:27:54.778: W/dalvikvm(1148): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
01-31 06:27:54.948: I/dalvikvm-heap(1148): Clamp target GC heap from 17.720MB to 16.000MB
01-31 06:27:54.948: D/dalvikvm(1148): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 114K, 3% free 15984K/16384K, paused 49ms, total 51ms
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.widget.ZoomControls
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:459)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.ZoomControlExternal$ExtendedZoomControls.<init>(ZoomControlExternal.java:124)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.ZoomControlExternal.createZoomControls(ZoomControlExternal.java:96)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.ZoomControlExternal.getControls(ZoomControlExternal.java:69)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.ZoomControlExternal.show(ZoomControlExternal.java:48)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.ZoomManager.invokeZoomPicker(ZoomManager.java:1208)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.startDrag(WebViewClassic.java:6321)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.handleTouchEventCommon(WebViewClassic.java:6025)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.onHandleUiTouchEvent(WebViewClassic.java:1398)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.onHandleUiEvent(WebViewClassic.java:1331)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.access$7200(WebViewClassic.java:146)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$PrivateHandler.dispatchUiEvent(WebViewClassic.java:7656)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchUiEvent(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:841)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchUiEvents(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:829)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchUiEvents(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:780)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.onTouchEvent(WebViewClassic.java:5825)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebView.onTouchEvent(WebView.java:1963)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7419)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4342)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4382)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
01-31 06:27:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Chore
```

Comment: how to use webview in android 4.2

Comment: Can you provide which device / Android version you are using?

Comment: i am trying in android emulator with OS version 4.2.with os version 2.2 it is working fine.is there any restriction for webview in android higher versions.if so how can i over come it.

Comment: @madanV are you using any javascriptinterface methods to webview in hold string?

Answer (score 0):

try with loadUrl

```
WebView w=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
w.loadUrl("http://www.mobilea.pcma.org/mobile/xml/sisap.asp?sid="+str+"&pn=AboutUs");
```

Comment: i want to load the hold string in webview

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for webview. It works on all versions of android. Copy and paste all the image files you use into all the "drawable" folders inside "res" folder of you project.  All the best..

```js
MainActivity.java:



package com.example.yourappname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView web;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    web = new WebView(this);  
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  
     //change the url below to the url you need
  
    web.loadUrl("http://www.xyxyxyxyxyxy.com");
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    setContentView(web);
}



public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
    
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        
    }
}

//flip screen not loading again
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}



@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(web.canGoBack()){
              web.goBack();
             }
            else
            {
             backButtonHandler();
            }
            return true;
        }

     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
public void backButtonHandler() {
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
    MainActivity.this);
  
 
  // Setting Dialog Title
    // Setting Dialog Message
      // You can delete the next 2 lines if you wish
  
  alertDialog.setTitle("");
  alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.dialog_icon);
  alertDialog.setMessage("Exit Now?");
  
      // Setting Icon to Dialog
  // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
  
  alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Exit",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      finish();
     }
  });
  
 // Setting Negative "NO" Button
  
  alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      // Write your code here to invoke NO event
      dialog.cancel();
     }
    });
 // Showing Alert Message
  alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

```html
AndroidManifest.xml:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yourappname"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_name_here"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>



activity_main.xml:



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```